# want to download a selected files checkbox in jsp

Tags: javascript, java, jsp

**I have created two jsp files index.jsp and downloadFiles.jsp.  I have attached the output of the code.On click of submit I want to download the selected files.please refer the code and guide me.
If I am wrong in the peocess please guide how to be better.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Ixpc.png)**
There is any way for multiple file download?
I have a jsp with differents checkbox, the user can check different checkbox's and then submit the action. I want to know how donload all the files linked to the checkbox's.

below is index.jsp

```
 <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>File Download</title>
</head>
<style>
table, th, td {
  border:1px solid black;
}
</style>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" 
integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60="
  crossorigin="anonymous">
  </script>
<body>

<h2>A basic HTML table</h2>
<form name="f" onsubmit="demo()">
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>select</th>
    <th>name</th>
    <th>download</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="subject" value="first"></td>
    <td>wel</td>
    <td> <a href="downloadFile.jsp" download="downloadfile">Download</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="subject" value="second"></td>
    <td>wip</td>
    <td> <a href="downloadFile.jsp">Download</a></td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="subject" value="third"></td>
    <td>info</td>
    <td><a href="downloadFile.jsp">Download</a></td>
  </tr>
  
</table>
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>

<%
String subject[]= request.getParameterValues("subject");
if(subject != null)
{
%>
<h4>You selected options </h4>
<ul>
<%
for(int i=0; i<subject.length; i++)
{
%>
<li><%=subject[i]%></li>
<%
}
%>
</ul>
<%
}
%>

</body>
</html>
```

downloadFiles.jsp

```
 <%@page import="java.io.FileInputStream"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
  pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>

<body>
  <%
response.setContentType("text/html");
String filename="hj.pdf";
String filepath="D:\\";
response.setContentType("APPLICATION/OCTET-STREAM");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + filename + "\"");
FileInputStream fileInputStream=new FileInputStream(filepath+filename);
int i;
while((i=fileInputStream.read())!=-1)
{
  out.write(i);
}
fileInputStream.close();
out.close();
%>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? what part of the code it not working, and does it give any errors for example?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi ramon de vries ,There is any way for multiple file download?
I have a jsp with differents checkbox, the user can check different checkbox's and then submit the action. I want to know how download all the files linked to the checkbox's.